# how to tell apache to accept serving a chrooted website?

Tags: apache, http, server

In the default state of the implementation of Apache, it seems like the default minimal permissions that the program can serve are as the following :

```
_ _ _ _ _ _r _ _ (for a file)
```

and

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ x (for a directory)
```

If not, when trying to reach the resource from a browser will just fail and a message like "can't access the resource" will just be displayed.

Now I am searching a way to modify this behavior, I need to tell apache to serve root files and directories (maybe in httpd.conf ? I couldn't find), so with the following permissions :

```
r _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ (for a file)
```

and

```
_ _ x _ _ _ _ _ _ (for a directory)
```

I have a website on my computer and I need only the root to be able to modify it but still when requested apache should serve the website as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to have nobody user in the chrooted /etc/passwd and /etc/group, so maybe:

Take full backups first!

```
chroot /path/to/chroot
adduser nobody
chgrp -R nobody /path/to/documentroot
chown -R root /path/to/documentroot
find /path/to/documentroot -type d -exec chmod -v u=r,g=rx,o=x '{}' \;
find /path/to/documentroot -type f -exec chmod -v u=r,g=r,o=r '{}' \;
```

From there, if it continues to error, tail the error log, and see if there's any additional issues.